# monotone function without derivative test

Tags: monotone-functions

**How i can prove this function is not a monotone function without the derivative test?**
                           $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^3}$$ thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It *is* monotonic on each interval  that make up its domain.

Comment: It is monotone on any interval where it is defined. It is only not monotone when considered across the point where it is not defined ($x=0.$)

Comment: thanks sir i got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not defined at $x=0$, so if you take an interval on which this function is defined, for example, $[a,b]$, either they are all positive or all negative. You can show that this function is monotone on any such interval by considering both cases, and using the equation: $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2).$